# Spigot Connection Refused: errno 61

Tags: spigot

I compiled the `spigot-1.19.4.jar` as instructed in the [official documentation](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/). My `mcpi` version on pip is 1.2.1 (I had to force that because my version of python threw exception for collection.Iterable). Minecraft is at the same 1.19.4 version and I can connect and play on my private server.

Running the following fails with `errno 61: Connection Refused`.

```
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft
mc = Minecraft.create()
```

When I run:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep :$PORT
```

The only answer is:

```
java      6341           iann   92u  IPv6 0x70811a3119f1ace5      0t0    TCP *:25565 (LISTEN)
```

---

I then tried:

```
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft
mc = Minecraft.create("127.0.0.1",25565)
mc.player.setTilePos(0,120,0)
```

Which then brings me to [this error](https://github.com/py3minepi/py3minepi/issues/16). So, one is supposed to leave the default port...?

---

One last this is, according to docs it could be related to wrong java version. I ran all the above in a shell where I first did:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home
```

as it is the java requested from doc and the one with which I built spigot.

Note: Firewall off. No Proxies.

---

---

Any idea welcome.